# Centering images in HTML with CSS

Tags: html, css, centering

My Images are not all centered. They start roughly in the middle and then go off to the right and side leaving a space on the left hand side

I am trying to make all my images centered neatly. I have 3 images in a row but there is a massive gap on the left hand side so the images start roughly in the centre and go of to the right. I want the all the images to be centered correctly. Here is my html code:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/50/50.jpg" alt="Great Wall of China" >
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/50/50.jpg" alt="Great Wall of China">
  </div>
   <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1002/50/50.jpg" alt="Great Wall of China">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: text-align:center to column

Answer (score 0):

```
.flex-container {
        display: flex;
        /* flex-direction: row; */
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .column {
        /* flex: 33.33%; */
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

---

Make from class="row" to class="flex-container"

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="column">

</div>
<div class="column">

</div>
<div class="column">

</div>
```